# "StackOverflow" error when using Recursion in Java

Tags: java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package plaindromenumbers;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author taha
 */
public class PlaindromeNumbers {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    int func1(int n)
    {
        if(n==1)
            return 1;

        return n*func1(n-1);
    }

    static boolean check=false;
    int func(int no)
    {

        String a=""+no;

        String reverse = new StringBuffer(a).reverse().toString();

        if(a.equals(reverse))
        {

            if(!a.contains("0"))
            {
               System.out.println("hey");
                check=true;
                return Integer.parseInt(a);
            }

        }

          //  else
          //  {
        func(no++);
        if(check==true)
        {
            return 0;
        }
           return 0;   
       }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter testcase");
       int testcase=in.nextInt(); 
       while(testcase>0)
       {
         int a=in.nextInt();
         PlaindromeNumbers obj=new PlaindromeNumbers();
           System.out.println(obj.func(a));
           testcase--;
       }
    }

}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question, but neat code dump.

Comment: If you're getting a stack overflow error, your recursion is too deep.  Either you have a code bug, or you need to redo this so it doesn't use recursion.

Comment: As a side note, don't explicitly compare to true and false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the problem:

```
func(no++);
```

Let's say `no` is 32.  This will pass 32 to `func` and *then* increment it.  Which means that you are once again calling the function with a value of 32.  And when that function hits this line, it will, once again, pass that 32 to `func`.  Hence, an infinite recursive loop.

You can fix this bug like this:

```
func(++no);
```

Now it will increase `no` *before* calling `func`.  `no` will be 33, it will match its reverse, and all will be well.

Comment: Well, OK, not all will be well unless you also do what csirmazbendeguz said.  But at least you won't get a stack overflow.

Comment: + for pointing out that postfix increment! lol!

Comment: Thanku soooo much the problem is solved finally..:-)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to return `func(no + 1)`, this way your code will return the next palindrome number (which I assume is what you want your code to do?). `check` is not needed. Why include `func1` when it's not even used by your code?

By the way, the stack overflow is caused by the infinite recursion of `func`.

Comment: Thanks for showing your interest csirmazbendeguz.:-) yes you are right there is a problem in function increment.When i'm changed this  func(no++) into return func(++no), then the problem wassolved.:-)